# .htaccess rewrite for url parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have been trying to make my urls "pretty" / human readable, the urls at the moment are:

```
[BASE_URL]/?action=viewProposal&proposaltitle=tesst
```

I want to rewrite them to be just `[BASE_URL]/tesst`

I tried using the following code and modifying it but it wouldn't work, ie. it didn't redirect the pages but didn't throw any errors.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^threads/(\d+)*$ ./thread.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ ./search.php?query=$1
```

Will the PHP GET functions still work properly as ?action defined whether its a view / edit / delete?

Comment: Do you want your preety url as **/viewProposal/tesst** (2 segments) or **/tesst** ? if it's **/tesst** then the answer posted bellow should work.

Comment: @starkeen how would this work if a parameter was an id then a slug for example:
/viewpost.php?id=2&slug=$1

Would this redirect urls only if the ID is two? 

if so how could you make it ignore the ID parameter and set the url as /[slug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming base url your index.php try following rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ index.php?action=viewProposal&proposaltitle=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That didnt work mate and its on a base url as in http://www.google.co.uk/?action=viewProposal&proposaltitle=tesst

Comment: Still there should be some page to handle the values or not? or are you using some framework?

Comment: No it is running on index.php but the urls are displaying as just a / then the parameters

Its a custom built CMS for proposals, just working on the pretty URL's at the moment. is there any reason it wouldnt have worked?

I did access the urls with index.php but they still didnt redirect.

Comment: Thanks that worked but it is returning a 404 error now, here is the URL it is producing

http://google.co.uk/viewProposal/viewProposaltesst/

Comment: Firstly, where are you using the rule why are you showing me the `google.co.uk` link are you redirecting the page?

Comment: the google.co.uk link is just an example, its on this page: http://proposals.99dcd11a723e7ff8ebaebb805-14042.sites.k-hosting.co.uk/?action=viewProposal&proposaltitle=tesst

Comment: try this it is working for me http://proposals.99dcd11a723e7ff8ebaebb805-14042.sites.k-hosting.co.uk/tesst as you mention in your requirement